# multiviewGeometryShader feature does not seems to be supported on the oculus 2, what alternatives?

Tags: vulkan, geometry-shader, oculusquest

So I wanted to modify the VrCuvbeWorld_Vulkan sample provided on the facebook website: https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/native/android/mobile-vrapi/
to add a geometry shader for the Oculus Quest 2.
However when I tried to enable the multiviewGeometryShader feature, I was granted by a VK_ERROR_FEATURE_NOT_PRESENT error. And on http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=10024#features_extensions the feature is said to not be supported.

I just need a geometry shader to calculate a value for each triangle. What would be a viable alternative?
On http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org they say that the geometryShader feature is supported. Therefore, is rendering eye by eye without the multiview extension a possible solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a device supports geometry shaders and also `VK_KHR_multiview`, that doesn't mean that both can be used in conjunction. That only works if the `multiviewGeometryShader` property is `true`. When we looked at this in detail last year, we couldn't find any device (besides some NVIDIA Quardo, I think) that supported multiview with geometry or tessellation shaders.

That means that you'll not be able to use geometry shaders with the `VK_KHR_multiview` extension for now. A good alternative could be to use [geometry shader instancing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Instancing) and use the geometry shader instance's invocation id to direct rendering into different layers:

```
gl_Layer = gl_InvocationID;
```

We have actually written a paper about different variants for multi view rendering in 2020: [Fast Multi-View Rendering for Real-Time Applications](https://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/research/publications/2020/unterguggenberger-2020-fmvr). The geometry shader instancing variant turned out to be one of the most performant alternatives. We only analyzed desktop, though. Performance characteristics could be different on mobile.